# Overload arrow operator as ref qualified

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

If the arrow operator of my class returns a pointer to internal data, **is it a good idea to always declare it as ref qualified** and have it work solely for l-values?

```
template <class T>
class Dummy
{
  T _data; // data lives within the class

public:
  Dummy() { /* some ctor logic */ }

  T* operator->() & { return &_data; }
  //              ^ this is the question

  T const* operator->() const& { return &_data; }
  //                         ^ this is the question
};
```

The reasoning behind this, is that using the arrow operator on a temporary instance would create a dangling pointer by default, since the data lives in my class.

Also, is there a canonical resource on ref qualifiers and overloading member access operators?

---

Note that the provided class example is purely for demo reasons, to provide a minimum example.

Comment: The lifetime of a temporary extends to the whole full-expression where it is created, so there would be no dangling pointer in for instance, `Wrapper<std::string>()->size();` Whether this would be useful or not depends on both `T` and the purpose of your wrapping.

Comment: @molbdnilo I had this note to begin with that the "Wrapper" class is just an example. I have no wrapping, the question touches "overloading arrow operator" in general. The data lives in the class, a lifetime extension may happen, but also within a function call someone may store the pointer e.g in a class (which doesn't offer lifetime extension). I get your point that all depends on the use, but are any concrete guidelines on this ?

Comment: The most concrete guidelines I can think of are "don't hand out pointers to internal data, especially not hidden behind convenient syntax" and "trying to protect against all possible mistakes adds much complexity for little gain".